# select chosen doesn't work with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

I want to use the select with search property this my HTML:

```
<div style="width:25em" >   
                <label> Hotel :</label> 

                   <select     ng-options="u for u in registrationCards | orderBy : 'hotelName' | unique:'hotelName'"  ng-model="selectedDist"  ng-change="selectAction(selectedDist)" >
                      <option value=""></option>
                   </select>

          </div >

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select').chosen( { width: '100%' } );  
});
</script>
```

The  problem that it doesn't take the element of the ng-option , i don't know why: 
this is the library js:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/master/dist/angular-chosen.min.js"></script>
```

How to resolve this? Thanks in advance

```
 this is my angular.module:
angular.module('etWeb.RegistrationCard',[ 'nvd3','base64']).service('RegistrationCardService', RegistrationCardService).controller('RegistrationCardController', RegistrationCardController).filter('startsWithFirstName', function() {});
```

and this my controler.js :

```
function RegistrationCardController($scope, $http,$state,$base64, RegistrationCardService,HotelsService) {
$scope.registrationCards = [];
function loadRegistrationCard() {
        RegistrationCardService.fetchAllRegistrationCard().then(function(d) {
            $scope.registrationCards = d;

            }, function(errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching Registration-Card');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You do have angular as dependency and you did not create any angular module/controller.

Comment: @Arashsoft i uptated my question , and this is the head is there any something missing?? thanks

Comment: Still I cannot see your controller code. How do you fill registrationCards. Is it an array of objects?

Comment: i updated the code  @Arashsoft

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated code I can find two issues:

1- `unique` filter is not available in angularjs. It is in `angular-ui`. If you want yo use it you have to include `angular-ui` in your project. And add `'ui.filters'` as a dependency to the angular module:

```
angular.module('etWeb.RegistrationCard', ['nvd3','base64', 'ui', 'ui.filters'])
```

or you can copy paste the code into your application:
Unique filter [source code link](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)

2- The second issue is ng-options works as `label for value in array`, So your ng-option expression must be:

```
// With unique filter
ng-options="u.hotelName for u in registrationCards | orderBy : 'hotelName' | unique:'hotelName'"
```

or

```
// Without unique filter
ng-options="u.hotelName for u in registrationCards | orderBy : 'hotelName'"
```